# React. How to save on LocalStorage when using Context

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to keep track of the number of favorites in the app.

It is working fine, except that I would like to store the numeric value in LocalStorage.

This is the custom Hook:

```
import { useState } from "react"

const initialState = {
  favCounter: 0
}

const useInitialState = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState)

  const incrementFav = () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      favCounter: state.favCounter + 1
    })
  }

  const decrementFav = () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      favCounter: state.favCounter - 1
    })
  }

  return {
    state,
    incrementFav,
    decrementFav
  }
}

export default useInitialState
```

and this is the component where I apply it:

```
  const { incrementFav, decrementFav } = useContext(AppContext)

  const handleFav = () => {
    if (liked) {
      decrementFav()
    } else { 
      incrementFav()
    }
  }

    <button onClick={
          () => { 
            handleFav()
          }
        }>
          <Icon size="28px" />
        </button>
```

Comment: What did you try to store it inside localStorage ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, paste code in case someone need it

```
import { useState } from "react"

const initialState = {
  // favCounter: 0
  favCounter: JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("favCounter"))
}

const useInitialState = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState)

  const incrementFav = () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      favCounter: state.favCounter + 1
    })
    window.localStorage.setItem("favCounter", JSON.stringify(state.favCounter + 1))
  }

  const decrementFav = () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      favCounter: state.favCounter - 1
    })
    window.localStorage.setItem("favCounter", JSON.stringify(state.favCounter - 1))
  }

  return {
    state,
    incrementFav,
    decrementFav
  }
}

export default useInitialState
```